# Discord.py @bot cannot play audio

Tags: python, discord.py

Take a look at this code:

```
async def playSound(ctx, channel, file, bot, connected):  
    ctx = ctx.message
    vc = await connected.channel.connect()
    await ctx.channel.send(embed = returnembed(preset = 'playingSound', info = str(channel)))
    player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player(file)
    player.start()
    while not player.is_done():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    player.stop()
    await vc.disconnect()
    await os.remove(file)

Notes:
ctx = ...well umm context... more specifically:
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def foo(ctx):
    pass
connected = ctx.author.voice
file = WAV_FILENAME
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= settings['callbotprefix_str'])
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
```

(Note: when I test this, I am indeed in a voice channel.)

I am trying to play a local audio file in a voice channel. While the bot successfully joins the voice channel every time, and I can confirm the file is not corrupted, I get greeted with a very "*pleasing*" exception:

```
Ignoring exception in command foo:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discord_package", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot_file", line 224, in tts
    await playsound(message, connected.channel, fileName, bot, connected)
  File "bot_file", line 318, in playsound
    player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player(file)
AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ffmpeg_player'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discord_package", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "whatever_the_core_thing_is", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "the_core_thing_again", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ffmpeg_player'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio()` to play an audio in the vc

```py
import discord

async def playSound(ctx, channel, file, bot, connected):  
    # ctx = ctx.message # i dont know what its doing, so i commented it out
    vc = await connected.channel.connect()
    await ctx.channel.send(embed = returnembed(preset = 'playingSound', info = str(channel)))
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(file))
    while vc.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # await vc.stop() # its gonna stop at the end, so i just commented it out too
    await vc.disconnect()
    os.remove(file)
```

tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: Hey @GhostOps, it didn't really work. I got basically the same error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.`

Comment: @AnonyMous do u have ffmpeg in your pc? it should be installed by default tho...

Comment: I'm pretty sure, for example I got `Requirement already satisfied:`  for all of the packages when I did `pip install discord`. I also tried `pip install FFmegPCAudio`, though pip couldn't find the package.

Comment: Sorry, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @AnonyMous ffmpeg is not a python module, its a package, it'll be available in all pc's by default, and `FFmegPCMAudio` is a class under `discord`. if u know the location of the ffmpeg executable file (i.e., ffmpeg.exe) you can pass the file path to the `executable` parameter to the `FFmpegPCMAudio`

Comment: Hmm you might be right there. I'll search through my disk.

Comment: @AnonyMous but actually, theres no need to search that tho... it'll run without any errors if your pc has ffmpeg, and you have to do something like `export $PATH 'ffmpeg.exe-filepath-goes-here` like that too (which i dont know exactly), but i dont know if thats necessary...

Comment: use `find` command in terminal to search any file in your system, if u dont know

Comment: @GhostOps ffmpeg is not available on all pcs by default

Comment: @WasiMaster ohh, ok, but do u have it?

Comment: @GhostOps yeah I do have it, manually installed

Comment: To download FFmpeg on mac windows or Linux you can just search `how to install FFmpeg on macOS/Linux/Windows10` in google and you'll get a lot of articles that go in-depth

Comment: @WasiMaster and also search `how to add path for ffmpeg` and do it too, it may make it work at some way i guess...

Comment: Yeah I do have ffmeg guys chill!